# How can we efficiently check whether a list of string contains a word from another list of strings?

Tags: python

Supposed I have a list of cursewords

```
curseword = ['fuxx', 'die', 'damn']
```

and if I am iterating through a list of sentence(list of string) to check if the sentence contains the curse word.

```
text = [ ['i','am','a','boy'] , [....] , [....] ]
```

I tried to do something like

```
for i in curse_words:
    for t in text:
        if i in t:
            // exsits
```

but it seems wrong and inefficient.

How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert you `curseword` list to a set, and then user `set.intersection` to check if words in sentence overlap with `cursword`.

```
In [10]: curseword = {'fuxx', 'die', 'damn'}

In [11]: text = [ ['i','am','a','boy'], ['die']]

In [21]: new_text = [int(bool(curseword.intersection(sent))) for sent in text]

In [22]: new_text
Out[22]: [0, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but what if I just wanna keep it simple like [1, 0, 1, 0...] ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. How does it work though? How can the length store the binary?

Comment: @Dawn17 `curseword.intersection(sent)` returns a new set, with overlapping elements, if the set is empty then `bool(empty_set)` is False, if the set is not not empty `bool(not_empty_set)` is True. That's how you would get a list of True and False. That's probably enough for your purpose, but I converted them to ints, since that's the format that you provided.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast `cursewords` to a `set` for increased lookup efficiency and use list comprehension which is more efficient than more generic looping in smaller cases:

```
curseword = {'fuxx', 'die', 'damn'}
text = [ ['i','am','a','boy'] , [....] , [....] ]
new_text = map(int, [all(b not in curseword for b in i) for i in text])
```

Comment: How can I change this just to store 1 or 0 depending on whether it has the curse word or not?

Comment: @StefanPochmann my bad, wrong variablename. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you want something different :

> **You can try without loop:**

```
curseword = ['fuxx', 'die', 'damn']
text = [ ['i','am','a','damn','boy']]

print(list(filter(lambda z:z!=[None],map(lambda x:(list(map(lambda y:y if x in y else None,text))),curseword))))
```

output:

```
[[['i', 'am', 'a', 'damn', 'boy']]]
```